# String loss in alarm manager

Tags: android

I have a problem with a text string attached to an alarm. It seems that when the alarm is triggered, the string attached to the alarm is null. Clearly I have made a mistake - but don't know where.

My code for setting the alarm is;

```
static void set_alarm(long alarm_time_in_millis,Context cont,AlarmManager alarm_manager,String str)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(cont, to_call_when_alarm_goes_off.class);
    intent.putExtra("string_passed_in_bundle", str); 

    Log.i("xx","set_alarm ["+str+"]"); // The string I see in the Log is correct
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont,0, intent, 0);

    alarm_manager.cancel(pIntent);

    alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time_in_millis, pIntent);
}
```

The code for receiving the alarm is as follows:

```
public class to_call_when_alarm_goes_off extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Bundle bundle_from_whoever_called_this_activity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        String str;

        bundle_from_whoever_called_this_activity = arg1.getExtras();

        str = bundle_from_whoever_called_this_activity.getString("string_passed_in_bundle");

        Log.i("xx","to_call_when_alarm_goes_off: TIME TO WAKE UP!!! ["+str+"]");

        try 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(arg0, dingaling.class);
            i.putExtra("string_passed_in_bundle", str);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            arg0.startActivity(i);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I set an alarm and then wait for it to be triggered, the log file will show something like this

```
set_alarm [Go to meeting]
to_call_when_alarm_goes_off: TIME TO WAKE UP!!! [null]
```

**EDIT:** Could there be some "super." function I've forgotten to call?

**EDIT:** I often get confused about what kind of context to pass to various functions, e.g. getBaseContext(),getApplicationContext(),"this" etc... If I had the wrong kind of context involved somewhere, could that cause this problem?

Comment: The first log statement (xx) has the correct string, I take it? Also, can you try renaming your extras key to something more uniquely identifiable than "string"? I doubt that's the issue, but you never know..

Comment: @Scen: yes the first log has the correct string - ok I'll try something other than "string".

Comment: @Scen: Changed from using "string" to "alarm_string", but it made no difference.

Comment: This is really weird, it should work. If you figure this out on your own, don't forget to update the question! I really want to know what's going on here, heh.

Answer (score 2):

I just copy and paste your code in my application and it is working perfectly. Just create on activity and copy your broadcast receiver. Take one button in the activity and onCLick of the button call your function for setAlarm.

I am able to get the string in broadcastReceiver.

Here is my code.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

                set_alarm(System.currentTimeMillis(), MainActivity.this, manager, "Time for tea");
            }
        });
    }


    static void set_alarm(long alarm_time_in_millis,Context cont,AlarmManager alarm_manager,String str)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(cont, to_call_when_alarm_goes_off.class);
        intent.putExtra("string_passed_in_bundle", str); 

        Log.i("xx","set_alarm ["+str+"]"); // The string I see in the Log is correct
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont,0, intent, 0);

        alarm_manager.cancel(pIntent);

        alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time_in_millis, pIntent);
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver is same as your so I am not putting it here.

And at last **declare the broadcast receiver in the manifest**

**Output**

```
set_alarm [Time for tea]
to_call_when_alarm_goes_off: TIME TO WAKE UP!!! [Time for tea]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to step through this code and make sure the string you are getting, is what you are expecting. I bet you are not getting what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Intent` instead of its `Bundle`, so...

```
str = arg1.getStringExtra("string");
```

Comment: The variable str was null if I used that method :-(

Answer (score 1):

When you change the key from

```
"string"
```

to

```
"alarm_string"
```

Do you still get a string in the to_call_when_alarm_goes_off class? Or do you get null?

What happens if you remove the cancel(pIntent) function here:

```
alarm_manager.cancel(pIntent);

alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,alarm_time_in_millis, pIntent);
```

Just trying to reduce the noise. "string" might be used in serialization or something, it could be getting confused. A more unique value also helps.

Comment: I am now using "string_passed_in_bundle" instead of "string". I am now receiving null in my broadcast receiver. I tried commenting out the cancel() - but it made no difference - still null.

Comment: I have edited to original question to reflect the latest version

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me.  I am calling the BroadcastReceiver through a custom intent with an intent filter in the AndroidManifest.  However I can't really say why that would make a difference.  That being said, the code below works.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
        setAlarm();
        break;
    }       
} 

private void setAlarm() {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    long interval = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000; // 10 seconds from now
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent();
    launchIntent.putExtra("your_key", "your string value");
    launchIntent.setAction(MyBroadcastReceiver.CUSTOM_INTENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, launchIntent, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,interval,
            pendingIntent);     
}
}
```

And the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.your_custom_intent";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String message = bundle.getString("your_key");
    Log.d("test", message);
}
}
```

And the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test2_2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.your_custom_intent" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```